# How to render in three.js surfaces double side without nasty side effects

Tags: three.js

Here is the problems

[image]

wireframe

[image: wireframe]

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "nasty side effects"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like depth buffer overlap problem. I think your scales are way off, and your depth buffer is not properly utilized.  Probably you should focus on scale of your triangles and how far away to put the camera.

Comment: You are absolutely right the problem was related to near-far values on the camera. Thanks to @akella for the explanation.

Comment: The solution in my case is to enable the logarithmicDepthBuffer,
`new WebGLRenderer({ logarithmicDepthBuffer: true });`